# How to integrate Mapbox Map SDK in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, mapbox, flutter-dependencies, mapbox-gl, mapbox-android

I'm a beginner `Flutter developer` and  was trying to integrate `Mapbox SDK` to Flutter. I used the official doc from Mapbox for android and did everything , but still the map isn't working.

[offical doc](https://docs.mapbox.com/android/maps/guides/install/)

**this was my error:**

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckDuplicatesRunnable
   > Duplicate class com.mapbox.android.core.location.LocationEngine found in modules jetified-common-23.4.0-runtime (com.mapbox.common:common:23.4.0) and jetified-mapbox-android-core-5.0.0-runtime (com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-core:5.0.0)
     Duplicate class com.mapbox.android.core.location.LocationEngineCallback found in modules jetified-common-23.4.0-runtime (com.mapbox.common:common:23.4.0) and jetified-mapbox-android-core-5.0.0-runtime (com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-core:5.0.0)
     Duplicate class com.mapbox.android.core.location.LocationEngineProvider found in modules jetified-common-23.4.0-runtime (com.mapbox.common:common:23.4.0) and jetified-mapbox-android-core-5.0.0-runtime (com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-core:5.0.0)
     Duplicate class com.mapbox.android.core.location.LocationEngineRequest found in modules jetified-common-23.4.0-runtime (com.mapbox.common:common:23.4.0) and jetified-mapbox-android-core-5.0.0-runtime (com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-core:5.0.0)
     Duplicate class com.mapbox.android.core.location.LocationEngineRequest$1 found in modules jetified-common-23.4.0-runtime (com.mapbox.common:common:23.4.0) and jetified-mapbox-android-core-5.0.0-runtime (com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-core:5.0.0)
     Duplicate class com.mapbox.android.core.location.LocationEngineRequest$Builder found in modules jetified-common-23.4.0-runtime (com.mapbox.common:common:23.4.0) and jetified-mapbox-android-core-5.0.0-runtime (com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-core:5.0.0)
     Duplicate class com.mapbox.android.core.location.LocationEngineResult found in modules jetified-common-23.4.0-runtime (com.mapbox.common:common:23.4.0) and jetified-mapbox-android-core-5.0.0-runtime (com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-core:5.0.0)
     Duplicate class com.mapbox.android.core.permissions.PermissionsListener found in modules jetified-common-23.4.0-runtime (com.mapbox.common:common:23.4.0) and jetified-mapbox-android-core-5.0.0-runtime (com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-core:5.0.0)
     Duplicate class com.mapbox.android.core.permissions.PermissionsManager found in modules jetified-common-23.4.0-runtime (com.mapbox.common:common:23.4.0) and jetified-mapbox-android-core-5.0.0-runtime (com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-core:5.0.0)
     Duplicate class com.mapbox.android.core.permissions.PermissionsManager$AccuracyAuthorization found in modules jetified-common-23.4.0-runtime (com.mapbox.common:common:23.4.0) and jetified-mapbox-android-core-5.0.0-runtime (com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-core:5.0.0)

     Go to the documentation to learn how to <a href="d.android.com/r/tools/classpath-sync-errors">Fix dependency resolution errors</a>.
```

gradle.properties file:

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1536M
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
MAPBOX_DOWNLOADS_TOKEN=checked this
```

styles.xml file -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <!-- Theme applied to the Android Window while the process is starting when the OS's Dark Mode setting is off -->
    <style name="LaunchTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar">
        <!-- Show a splash screen on the activity. Automatically removed when
             the Flutter engine draws its first frame -->
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/launch_background</item>
    </style>
    <!-- Theme applied to the Android Window as soon as the process has started.
         This theme determines the color of the Android Window while your
         Flutter UI initializes, as well as behind your Flutter UI while its
         running.

         This Theme is only used starting with V2 of Flutter's Android embedding. -->
    <style name="NormalTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">?android:colorBackground</item>
        
    </style>
    <string name="mapbox_access_token">checked this</string>
</resources>
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.mapbox_try2">
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
      <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
   <application
        android:label="mapbox_try2"
        android:name="${applicationName}"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <!-- Specifies an Android theme to apply to this Activity as soon as
                 the Android process has started. This theme is visible to the user
                 while the Flutter UI initializes. After that, this theme continues
                 to determine the Window background behind the Flutter UI. -->
            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
              android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
              />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
             This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

**android/build.gradle**

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.7.10'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
          url 'https://api.mapbox.com/downloads/v2/releases/maven'
          authentication {
            basic(BasicAuthentication)
          }
          credentials {
            // Do not change the username below.
            // This should always be `mapbox` (not your username).
            username = "mapbox"
            // Use the secret token you stored in gradle.properties as the password
            password = "checked this"
          }
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.2.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**app/build.gradle**

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

android {
    compileSdkVersion flutter.compileSdkVersion
    ndkVersion flutter.ndkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.example.mapbox_try2"
        // You can update the following values to match your application needs.
        // For more information, see: https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#reviewing-the-gradle-build-configuration.
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.mapbox.maps:android:10.12.1'
 



}
```

MY code :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:mapbox_gl/mapbox_gl.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        // This is the theme of your application.
        //
        // Try running your application with "flutter run". You'll see the
        // application has a blue toolbar. Then, without quitting the app, try
        // changing the primarySwatch below to Colors.green and then invoke
        // "hot reload" (press "r" in the console where you ran "flutter run",
        // or simply save your changes to "hot reload" in a Flutter IDE).
        // Notice that the counter didn't reset back to zero; the application
        // is not restarted.
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: MapboxMap(
        accessToken:
            "checked this",
        onMapCreated: (MapboxMapController controller) {
          // Do something when the map is created
        },
        initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
          target: LatLng(37.7749, -122.4194),
          zoom: 12,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I  used 'mapbox_gl: ^0.16.0' package to get it. and when i run in Vs code  it shows Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses , and i tried using chatGPT and got this-

app/build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.mapbox.maps:android:10.12.1'
 
implementation ('com.mapbox.maps:android:10.12.1'){
   configurations {
    all {
        exclude group: 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk', module: 'mapbox-android-core'
        exclude group: 'com.mapbox.common', module: 'common'
        exclude group: 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk', module: 'mapbox-sdk-services'
        exclude group: 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk', module: 'mapbox-sdk-turf'
        exclude group: 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk', module: 'mapbox-sdk-geojson'
        exclude group: 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk', module: 'mapbox-sdk-constants'
        exclude group: 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk', module: 'mapbox-sdk-core'
    }
}
}


}
```

after this the errror was gone and shows white scren for 0.5 second and gone , the " Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'..." is stuck/in loop , its not completing or stopping.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the solution which was just related to `multiDexing`.

Just go to your app module `build.gradle` file and add

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        ...
        minSdkVersion 21 
        targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion
        multiDexEnabled true <-- add this line
    }
    ...
}
```

And to the dependencies section:

```
dependencies {
    implementation "androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1" <-- add this line too
}
```

This is the link to the docs: https://developer.android.com/build/multidex#groovy

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

no, still error with mapbox_gl and flutter_mapbox_navigation:

```
Duplicate class com.mapbox.android.core.location.LocationEngine found in modules jetified-common-23.2.3-runtime (com.mapbox.common:common:23.2.3) and jetified-mapbox-android-core-5.0.0-runtime (com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-core:5.0.0)
     Duplicate class com.mapbox.android.core.location.LocationEngineCallback found in modules jetified-common-23.2.3-runtime (com.mapbox.common:common:23.2.3) and jetified-mapbox-android-core-5.0.0-runtime (com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-core:5.0.0)
     Duplicate class com.mapbox.android.core.location.LocationEngineProvider found in modules jetified-common-23.2.3-runtime (com.mapbox.common:common:23.2.3) and jetified-mapbox-android-core-5.0.0-runtime (com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-core:5.0.0)
     Duplicate class com.mapbox.android.core.location.LocationEngineRequest found in modules jetified-common-23.2.3-runtime (com.mapbox.common:common:23.2.3) and jetified-mapbox-android-core-5.0.0-runtime (com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-core:5.0.0)
     Duplicate class com.mapbox.android.core.location.LocationEngineRequest$1 found in modules jetified-common-23.2.3-runtime (com.mapbox.common:common:23.2.3) and jetified-mapbox-android-core-5.0.0-runtime (com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-core:5.0.0)
     Duplicate class com.mapbox.android.core.location.LocationEngineRequest$Builder found in modules jetified-common-23.2.3-runtime (com.mapbox.common:common:23.2.3) and jetified-mapbox-android-core-5.0.0-runtime (com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-core:5.0.0)
     Duplicate class com.mapbox.android.core.location.LocationEngineResult found in modules jetified-common-23.2.3-runtime (com.mapbox.common:common:23.2.3) and jetified-mapbox-android-core-5.0.0-runtime (com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-core:5.0.0)
     Duplicate class com.mapbox.android.core.permissions.PermissionsListener found in modules jetified-common-23.2.3-runtime (com.mapbox.common:common:23.2.3) and jetified-mapbox-android-core-5.0.0-runtime (com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-core:5.0.0)
     Duplicate class com.mapbox.android.core.permissions.PermissionsManager found in modules jetified-common-23.2.3-runtime (com.mapbox.common:common:23.2.3) and jetified-mapbox-android-core-5.0.0-runtime (com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-core:5.0.0)
     Duplicate class com.mapbox.android.core.permissions.PermissionsManager$AccuracyAuthorization found in modules jetified-common-23.2.3-runtime (com.mapbox.common:common:23.2.3) and jetified-mapbox-android-core-5.0.0-runtime (com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-core:5.0.0)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).